# Cannot run Robolectric tests with Gradle and Android Studio - StyleData not found

Tags: java, android, gradle, robolectric

I downloaded [deckard-gradle](https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle) project and I have created my own with this temple.

My problem is that Robolectric.2.3 does not want to run test for class.

This is my error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: huh? can't find parent for StyleData{name='AppTheme', parent='Theme_AppCompat_Light_DarkActionBar'}
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager$StyleResolver.getParent(ShadowAssetManager.java:365)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager$StyleResolver.getAttrValue(ShadowAssetManager.java:350)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.findAttributeValue(ShadowResources.java:293)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.attrsToTypedArray(ShadowResources.java:196)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.access$000(ShadowResources.java:55)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources$ShadowTheme.obtainStyledAttributes(ShadowResources.java:494)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources$ShadowTheme.obtainStyledAttributes(ShadowResources.java:489)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources$ShadowTheme.obtainStyledAttributes(ShadowResources.java:484)
    at android.content.res.Resources$Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources.java)
    at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:380)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:104)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
    at pl.grzeslowski.historia_miasta.activities.MainActivity_.onCreate(MainActivity_.java:31)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
    at org.fest.reflect.method.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:112)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:147)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:265)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:144)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:154)
    at pl.grzeslowski.historia_miasta.activities.MainActivityTest.testSomething(MainActivityTest.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:250)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:103)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:355)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Any progress on this? I tried trick from the last comment in https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/979 but still failed.

Answer (score 0):

I run into similar problem, RobolectricTestRunner can't find the Android library dependencies. To resolve this issue you need to extend from RobolectricTestRunner to pull them in.android-maven-plugin unpacks your APK dependencies depending on version of the plugin into "target/unpack/apklibs" or to "target/unpacked-libs". The example I pasted below resolve problem for second one.

```
public class MyTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {

    public MyTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
        super(testClass);
    }

    @Override
    protected AndroidManifest createAppManifest(FsFile manifestFile, FsFile resDir, FsFile assetsDir) {
        return new MavenAndroidManifest( manifestFile,  resDir,  assetsDir);
    }

    public static class MavenAndroidManifest extends AndroidManifest {
        public MavenAndroidManifest(FsFile androidManifestFile, FsFile resDirectory, FsFile assetsDirectory) {
            super(androidManifestFile, resDirectory, assetsDirectory);
        }

        public MavenAndroidManifest(FsFile libraryBaseDir) {
            super(libraryBaseDir);
        }

        @Override
        protected List<FsFile> findLibraries() {
            // Change "target/unpacked-libs" to "target/unpack/apklibs" 
            //if youe have older version of android-maven-plugin
            FsFile unpack = getBaseDir().join("target/unpacked-libs");
            if (unpack.exists()) {
                FsFile[] libs = unpack.listFiles();
                if (libs != null) {
                    return Arrays.asList(libs);
                }
            }
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        @Override
        protected AndroidManifest createLibraryAndroidManifest(FsFile libraryBaseDir) {
            return new MavenAndroidManifest(libraryBaseDir);
        }
    }
}
```

Later in test cases use it like this:

```
@RunWith(MyTestRunner.class)
@Config(emulateSdk = 18)
public class MyActivityTest{
}
```